# How to show warning in action of Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm learning Zend Framework 1.
In normal php file, I write below:

```
$p=1/0;
```

There'll be a warning like below:

```
Warning: Division by zero in D:\ZendProject\TestProject\public\2-2.php on line 8
```

But when I write  "$p=1/0;" in a ZF Action function, such as below:

```
public function doAction ()
    {
        $p=1/0;

    }
```

Nothing displays, not any warning information.
How can I turn on the warning display?

Comment: Edit your php.ini: `display_errors=On`

Answer (score 0):

You can put it **`.htaccess`** file like bellow

**`php_value error_reporting 2147483647`**

But for that you need in apache

**`AllowOverride All`**

For more see [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107828/how-can-i-turn-on-php-errors-display-on-just-a-subfolder**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107828/how-can-i-turn-on-php-errors-display-on-just-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code in same environment and you can't see any errors just in your ZF1 then most likely you need to amend a value in your config.ini

```
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
```

to

```
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```